# Why tableau data connection isn't showing any of my schemas?

Tags: jdbc, db2, driver, tableau-api, data-warehouse

I'm using Tableau Desktop 2021.1 on Mac. I want to connect to a IBM DB2 on Cloud data warehouse using JDBC connection.

I did the following steps to configure the setup:

1. In order to do this I've installed IBM Data Server Driver 11.5 (v11.5.5_macos_dsdriver.dmg)
2. I copied the required jar file to Tableau driver folder: /Library/Tableau/Drivers/db2jcc.jar
3. Then I set up the SSL connection using terminal and create the properties file.
4. I'm selecting the JDBC connection on Tableau, I add the url, pw, properties file and I'm able to connect.

After this it says I'm connected and signed in, I see no schemas or tables under the data connection.

I see there a dropdown which says: select database and enter database name. I tried to search for the db name as it appears on the connection details on the db cloud, I tried searching for schemas or tables, even tried with '*' if it lists any schemas. Sadly neither of these worked and I feel like I'm in a dead end.

I'm wondering if it is a driver issue or I need to copy some other files to the Tableau driver folder or what else can I try?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Usually you need also the db2jcc_license_cu.jar (for connecting to Db2-LUW). But why not check if other jdbc applications work with your configuration (example SquirrelSQL, or DBeaver, or DbVisualizer etc) - in other words check if tableau configuration is the issue.

Comment: dbeaver is working perfectly, no issues there. I checked the jar file that you referring to and its not existing in the driver folder. How is that possible?

Comment: what was the exact full filename of the Db2 driver you downloaded? (or just edit your question to show the text only output of the command `db2level` , which should be located somewhere on your system.)

Comment: This is the full name of the driver that I downloaded from ibm official page: v11.5.5_macos_dsdriver.dmg

Comment: `v11.5.5_macos_dsdriver.dmg` includes `db2_db2driver_for_jdbc_sqlj.zip` which contains db2jcc4.jar and sqlj4.zip etc. Please unzip that and copy the `db2jcc4.jar` file to the Tableau drivers directory, and retry (remove db2jcc.jar , not sure where you got that).

Comment: I've checked the zip files and copied db2jcc4.jar , removed the other one and the issue still there, no schemas there, not able to add DB name (DB name is in the connection url, otherwise I'm not able to connect). Do you have any other tips to try?

Comment: Maybe open a question on the tableau-desktop community forum?  I do not have a MacOs environment. On MS-Windows, tableau-desktop uses CLI (not jdbc) and seems to work ok with Db2-on-cloud. But I do not know how it works on MacOS. There is currently no Linux x64 version of tableau-desktop for me to try.  Try   https://community.tableau.com

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've opened a question on tableau community few days ago, but no answer yet. :/